# Hibernate Interceptor : entity intercepted on update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, interceptor

I am building REST API. And I have an entity and Interceptor. The Interceptor extends EmptyInterceptor(Hibernate). When I create a new object of the entity, the interceptor is called. However, when i update the object of the entity in the code, the interceptor is also called. But when I update the object of the entity using put request, the interceptor is not called and the entity is updated in the database. Any ideas how I can solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you could use onFlashDirty

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).